# Including a custom module model / block into template

Tags: template, blocks, module, class

I'm trying to follow [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/) guide. But I want to add the template directly into the homepage using `cms.xml`, something like: `<block type="trendingproducts/data" name="trending.products" template="blocks/bestsellers.phtml"/>` where my template is in `templates/blocks/bestsellers.phtml`.

How can I tie this tutorial class into the template if it is saved as something like: `app/code/local/Company/Trending/Block/Data.php` with the class defined as: `class Company_Trending_Block_Data extends Mage_Core_Block_Template`?

I've also set the `config.xml` inside the `Trending/etc` module directory as something like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Trending>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Trending>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <Company_Trending>
                <class>Company_Trending_Block</class>
            </Company_Trending>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('trendingproducts/data')->setBlockId('trending.products')->setTemplate('blocks/bestsellers.phtml')->toHtml() ?>` inside your template.

If this is not the case and you want to add the block in a CMS page I suggest you to use the design update in the CMS page within the admin where you can paste your code.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="trendingproducts/data" name="trending.products" template="blocks/bestsellers.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

There is a third way to make this work, using the content tab inside your Homepage CMS page:

```
{{block type="trendingproducts/data" name="trending.products" template="blocks/bestsellers.phtml"}}
```

Comment: The issue is that (according to the tutorial) I want to bypass using a dynamic block created in the admin CMS and just load the template directly from the `layout/cms.xml` layout update. But somewhere in the mix I'm going wrong and I can't see where.

Comment: @mbalparda I think you mean "inside your block class", not "inside your template". You can't set the block's template from *inside* the template.

Comment: @Jonathan see my edit.

Comment: @pspahn I'm referring to the layout update which I was sure was the right nomenclature for what I am talking about CMIIAW(?) I.e. the layout xml files.